# A chessboard Combinatorics Problem

Tags: combinatorics, chessboard

> How many ways are there to put numbers $1,2,3,\cdots, n^2$ into a $n\times n$ chessboard s.t. the sum of the numbers on every row and every column is even.

### My approach to this problem (Ideas)

I want to use **parity** to solve the problem. First, see all odd numbers as $1$, and all even numbers as $2$.  Using the addition principle, we can figure out how many $0,1$ arrangements are there. After that, for each arrangement, using the multiplication principle, we can solve for all the arrangements.

#### Observations

1. When $n=1$, there is no way to satisfy the question. (Trivial)
2. When $n=2$, there is no way to satisfy the question. (Brute force)
3. When $n=3$, there is no way to satisfy the question. (Brute force)
4. When $n=4$?

When I got to $n=4$, I got stuck because the are way to many cases to write down if I brute force the problem.

#### Trying to solve the general formula

I GUESS there exists more than $0$ ways only for $4\mid n$. I already turned the original problem into an equivalent problem s.t. the numbers are all $0$ s and $1$ s. Now I may have to solve for the general  formula for all $4m\times 4m\;(m\in \mathbb{N})$ chessboards, and prove that for all $n$ s.t. $4\nmid n$, there are $0$ possible arrangements.

#### Note

1. I hope this is not a duplication. If there are any mistakes in my question, I will edit it.
2. If two or more arrangements can be turned into one another by rotations and flips, these arrangements are still different arrangements.

### Edit

The GUESS above is wrong. I should prove $\forall m\in \mathbb{N}$ s.t. $2\mid m$ and $m>2$, there exists at least one possible arrangement for a $m\times m$ chessboard. Then, I should find the general formula for the $m\times m$ chessboard.

Comment: What's the source? Is it a computing problem? While you're right that we require $ 4 \mid n$, counting the number of solutions seems like a lot of work to me.

Comment: Ah, I see where I made a mistake. $\quad$ I can reframe this as the number of bipartite graphs on $ m, m$ vertices with $2m^2$ edges, that can be decomposed into distinct cycles. However, counting them still seems hard.

Comment: You don't need "brute force" to see that there are no solutions when $n$ is odd; if $n$ is odd then $1+2+3+\cdots+n^2$ is odd.

Comment: At minimum, you need $\frac{n^2(n^2+1)}2$ even. This is only true of $n$ is even.

Comment: @bof My strategy is a bit primordial. Thanks for the comments.

Comment: For $4\times 4,$ here is a simple example: $$\begin{pmatrix}1&1&0&0\\1&1&0&0\\0&0&1&1\\0&0&1&1\end{pmatrix}.$$

Comment: If you have an example with $2m\times 2m,$ then you can easily find an example that is $(2m+4)\times (2m+4).$ So there are examples for all even $n\geq 4.$

Comment: Particularly, I want to focus on $n=4$. If I can find the number of all possible $0,1$ arrangements $x$,  then the number of all possible arrangements is $x\times 8!\times 8!$. The argument should be similar for all even numbers greater than or equal to $4$. But, how to find $x$ is another problem.

Comment: @E.Huang The number of $0, 1$ arrangements for $n = 4$ is $246$. For $n = 6$ it's $8784000$.

Comment: @WhatsUp I’m curious. How do you come up with the two numbers of possible $0,1$ arrangements for $n=4,6$? What’s your strategy?

Comment: @E.Huang Nothing mysterious. I wrote a simple program to do it. Unfortunately $n = 8$ will be too large for my naive method. At this point I would like to know where this problem comes from, and is there a clever method to be expected?

Comment: @WhatsUp I think there is a “pure math” method to approach this problem.

Comment: This is a generalization of a competition math problem. The one in the competition focuses on $n=4$. That tells us, for small values of $n$, we can still use the counting method.

Comment: @E.Huang Why do you think so? If, for example, you get the problem from a published math contest, then it is reasonable to expect a "pure math" solution. If the problem just appeared in your mind and you cannot solve it, then why can one expect a clever method?

Comment: @E.Huang I think you should probably focus on the $n = 4$ case, as it doesn't seem to be possible to generalize it to arbitrary $n$. For $n = 4$ there should be clever methods that can solve it with reasonable amount of effort.

Comment: @WhatsUp Personally, I *suspect* that you are right.  The only 3 (general) approaches that I know of, for a problem like this are [1] the direct approach, which comments to this posting have already focused on, where $(n=4)$ [2] Inclusion-Exclusion and [3] recursion.  To me, each of these three approaches **seems** as if its application will get very ugly, **fast**.  However, the fact that it seems that way to me is obviously inconclusive.

Comment: @user2661923 Well, at least I can solve the $n = 4$ case by hand in reasonable amount of time (~15 minutes including writing down a solution on paper, if I were attending that math contest). There are only $246$ total cases and a bunch of symmetries to explore, e.g. by permuting rows and columns. I will not post such an answer though, as typing all these matrices in MathJax would take forever. Therefore you can still suspect ...

Comment: For $n=4$ I get $246$ solutions by hand, with "reasonable effort" but no cleverness. (a) Two rows with $4$ ones: $\binom42=6$. (b) Two columns with $4$ ones: $6$. (c) One row with $4$ ones: $4\cdot3\cdot\binom42=72$. (d) Two columns with $4$ ones: $72$. That leaves matrices with two ones in each row and column, i.e., $2$-regular subgraphs of $K_{4,4}$. (e) $2C_4$: $\binom42\binom42/2=18$. (f) $C_8$: $4!4!/8=72$. Total: $6+6+72+72+18+72=246$.

Comment: Oops. In my last comment (counting by hand for $n=4$) by "(d) Two columns with $4$ ones" I meant "(d) **one** column with $4$ ones."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do not think there is any formula to count the number of matrices. You can use dynamic programming to count the number of matrices for $n\le 10$, but the time required is $O(n^32^{2n})$, so this quickly becomes infeasible. Here is the data I found (not in OEIS):

| $n$ | $4$ | $6$ | $8$ | $10$ |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| # matrices | $246$ | $8784000$ | $111869178489670$ | $384868991272320758246400$ |

Here is a sketch of how the program works. Let $N(n,m,k,v)$ be the number of $m\times n$ matrices with elements in $\mathbb Z/2\Bbb Z$ which have exactly $k$ ones, where every row has an even number of ones, and for which the sum of the row vectors is $v$. By considering all possible choices for the last row of the matrix, we have
$$
N(n,m,k,v)=
\begin{cases}
\sum_r N(n,m-1,k-|r|,v\oplus r) & m \ge 1
\\
1 & m=0, k=0,v=\vec 0
\\
0 & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$
where the sum ranges over all vectors $r\in (\Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z)^n$ with an even number of ones, $|r|$ is the number of ones in $r$, and $\oplus$ is the usual vector addition in $(\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z)^n$. Your problem calls for $N(n,n,n^2/2, \vec 0)$.

Comment: +1 for the effort. This method gets results that are much much larger than my naive algorithm - sadly still cannot go much further.

Comment: How in the world were you ever able to run a computer program that computed a number that is approximately $4 \times 10^{(23)}?$  Was this done on a normal PC, or do you have access to a *business* computer?  For the computer that this program ran on, how much ram was available, and what cpu-chip is the computer using?

Comment: @user2661923 It took 3min on a midrange laptop. Remember big-oh notation obscures a constant, you can’t just plug in 10 for $n$ to get a notion of how long it will take for that particular $n$.